# schedule RDS database shutdown and startup

Tags: snapshot

1. How to automate bringing my RDS database offline and online via scripts/ANY PROCEDURE to save money? Note before to OFFLINE, I need to take a final SNAP SHOT,want to AUTOMATE this also. 
   The steps as follows.. 1)Take a SNAPSHOT 2)Shutdown Instance 3)STARTUP Instance in morning with same DATA available for Business.
2. When I put a RDS offline to stop the "work hours" counter running and billing me, when I bring it back online will it still have the same content (i.e will all my data stay there, or will it have to be a blank DB?).

Comment: I would have thought there would be more interest in how to schedule RDS starts and stops. Kumar, did you find your solution?